# Access the data through JSON AJAX array -> object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I have this json result:

```
  [{
    "website": "http://www.rlbuht.nhs.uk",
    "sub_type": "Hospital",
    "sector": "NHS Sector",
    "postcode": "L3 5PS",
    "phone": "0151 706 2000",
    "partial_postcode": "L3",
    "parent_o_d_s_code": "RQ6",
    "parent_name": "Royal Liverpool and Broadgreen University Hospitals NHS Trust",
    "organisation_type": "Hospital",
    "organisation_status": "Visible",
    "organisation_name": "Royal Liverpool University Dental Hospital",
    "organisation_id": "41513",
    "organisation_code": "RQ614",
    "longitude": "-2.9669923782348633",
    "latitude": "53.408927917480469",
    "is_pims_managed": "True",
    "fax": "0151 706 5806",
    "email": "",
    "county": "Merseyside",
    "city": "Liverpool",
    "address3": "",
    "address2": "",
    "address1": "Pembroke Place"
}]
```

And here is my code to access the url and get the json which works fine:

```
$("#search_hospitals").on('click', function(p_oEvent_search_hospitals) {

     var api_search_hospitals, postcode, nhs_hospitals;
     p_oEvent_search_hospitals.preventDefault();
     postcode = $('#input_nhs_h').val();
     api_search_hospitals = 'https://data.gov.uk/data/api/service/health/hospitals/partial_postcode?partial_postcode=' + postcode;

     $.ajax(api_search_hospitals, {

         complete: function(p_OXHR, p_sStatus) {

             nhs_hospitals = $.parseJSON(p_OXHR.responseText);

             alert(nhs_hospitals[0].postcode);

         }

     });
 });
```

I'm just testing with `alert(nhs_hospitals[0].postcode);` to see if I can get the data but I always get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nhs_hospitals[0].postcode')`...

Can someone please help me in saying what i'm doing wrong, why I'm getting "undefined"? Thank you

To make it easier I did:

```
complete: function(p_OXHR, p_sStatus) {

        nhs_hospitals = $.parseJSON(p_OXHR.responseText);
        hospital = nhs_hospitals.result[0];

        alert(hospital.postcode);

    }
```

Comment: What's is content of nhs_hospitals?

Comment: The problem is that the `nhs_hospitals` object has a `result` array inside it. If you reference that, you should get the result, as I've posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(p_oEvent_search_hospitals) {

     var api_search_hospitals, postcode, nhs_hospitals;
     p_oEvent_search_hospitals.preventDefault();
     postcode = 'EC1A'
     api_search_hospitals = 'https://data.gov.uk/data/api/service/health/hospitals/partial_postcode?partial_postcode=' + postcode;

     $.ajax(api_search_hospitals, {

         complete: function(p_OXHR, p_sStatus) {

             nhs_hospitals = $.parseJSON(p_OXHR.responseText);
             console.log(nhs_hospitals);
             alert(nhs_hospitals.result[0].postcode);

         }

     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>search</button>
```

This should work. The problem is that the `nhs_hospitals` object has a `result` array inside it. If you reference that, you will get your result.

Comment: why should I use the "result" word before the [0]?

Comment: yeah can you cite any documentation explaining this?

Comment: Because that is the format of the response provided by your API. If you go to:
`https://data.gov.uk/data/api/service/health/hospitals/partial_postcode?partial_postcode=EC1A`, you will see that the response has a `success` flag and a `results` array

Comment: @Aelliott1485 All of the documentation I have (and need) is that the API's response that can be seen here: `https://data.gov.uk/data/api/service/health/hospitals/partia‌​l_postcode?partial_p‌​ostcode=EC1A`

As long as you don't have access to changing the API, you'll need to do a `.result`. I'm not sure if there's any documentation that the site provides, that might get you a different result

Comment: yeah I looked at the jQuery docs for [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) but it doesn't mention the result property...

Comment: @Aelliott1485 It doesn't have anything to do with jQuery. It's just part of the API response, as you would've realized already :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a,

```
console.log(nhs_hospitals)
```

and see if it prints the array if not then that means `p_OXHR.responseText` does not contain anything. Are you sure the `responseText` is what is being sent from the server?

Comment: yep, I got {success: true, result: Array} in the console

Comment: OK if `console.log(nhs_hospitals)` prints `{success: true, result: Array}` then you should update the code to

`alert(nhs_hospitals.result[0].postcode);`

if not post the response

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 $.ajax(api_search_hospitals, {
                    success: function (data) {

                        nhs_hospitals = $.parseJSON(data);

                        alert(nhs_hospitals[0].postcode);

                    }

                });
```